# how to access my written django libraries

Tags: python, django

i have a project in django named x and i have an app name y in x. in the directry of y i have my views and i write a function in one script named project that is wrapped into two other directories named dir1 and dir2 that dir1 is placed in y directory how to to access my function i tried:

```
from dir1.dir2 import project
```

and

```
from .dir1.dir2 import project
```

and

```
from dir1.dir2.project import *
```

and

```
from .dir1.dir2.project import *
```

my directory is like this:

```
x
  x
  y
     views.py
     dir1
        dir2
           project
```

i have other libraries in dir2 and when i take the files and insert into y directory and then i use from project import * it works correctly.

> and i had a project named b and i renamed it to x is it possible to
>   related this.

how can i fix this

Answer (score 1):

simple one liner would be

```
from y.dir1.dir2 import project
```

Comment: add 'y' to installed apps as well in setings.py

Comment: i had added it.

Comment: where are you calling the function?

Comment: i dont call my function i just import them to my views.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178781/discussion-between-nimish-bansal-and-abolfazl-ebadi).

Answer (score 0):

I should create

> `__init__.py`

in each directory I that I created.